# 'went with it' and 'hard five massive major ammunition sites' meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image: screenshot of the caption: "And a lot of people went with it." with "went with it" underlined.]

[image: frame from a video of President Trump with the caption "we had very very hard five massive major ammunition sites" underlined.]

The source is https://youtu.be/5QZmMWSVw_4?t=159

1. What does *went with it* mean?
2. *'We had very,very hard five massive major ammunition sites'* -> What is it about?

Comment: The context is important in understanding these sentences, and even then, it's confusing. Many politicians have a confusing verbal style.

Answer (score 1):

He's actually saying "We hit very, very hard, five massive major ammunition sites."

Now that you know that he's talking about a hit on an ammunition site, hopefully the "went with it" becomes clear - they were killed as a result of the attack.

Answer (score 0):

Please, please don't use Trump to learn English haha.

For "went with it": A boat that was on the ocean that suddenly sails over a current "went with the current" or "went with it". Likewise, things happened and, like a current, people "went with it".

For the other sentence: The subtitles are wrong here, but even if they were right, a more competent English speaker would say, "We hit five major ammunition sites *hard*".